For a metric space $X$, any map $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$ satsifies $\textrm{dil} f = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R} } \textrm{dil}_x f$
For metric spaces $(X,d_X),(Y,d_Y)$, a mapping $f:X\to Y$ said to be Lipschitz if $d_Y(f(x),f(x')) \leq Cd_X(x,x')$ for some $C\geq 0$, and $C$ is said to be a Lipschitz constant. The smallest Lipschitz constant is said to be the dilatation of $f$ and denoted $\textrm{dil}f$. We define the dilatation of a non-Lipschitz function to be $\infty$.
We can also define dilatation locally. The dilatation of $f$ at $x$ is defined by
$\begin{equation} \textrm{dil}_xf = \textrm{inf}\left\{\textrm{dil}f|_U|U\textrm{ is a neighborhood of }x\right\}\end{equation}$
The question is the following:

For a metric space $X$ and any map $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$, prove that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R} }\textrm{dil}_x f=\textrm{dil}f$.

My attempt
Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a neighborhood of any element, we have $\mathrm{dil}f \geq \mathrm{dil}_xf$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so that $\mathrm{dil}f \geq \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R} }\mathrm{dil}_xf$.
So it is enough to show that $\mathrm{dil}f \leq \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R} }\mathrm{dil}_xf$. I guess proving that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R} }\mathrm{dil}_xf$ is a (global) Lipschitz constant of $f$ should be enough, but I was unable to do so.  According to this post, the fact that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ seems to be very important as there is a counterexample otherwise, but I was unable to point out which properties of $\mathbb{R}$ are important.
Any help is appreciated.

I consider the case $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}{\rm dil}_{t}f < \infty$. Note that then $f$ is continuous.
Fix $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x<y$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. To each $t \in [x,y]$ choose an open and bounded interval $U_t$ such that $t \in U_t$ and
$$
{\rm dil}f|_{U_t} < {\rm dil}_tf  + \varepsilon.
$$
Since $[x,y]$ is compact, there are finitely many $U_t$ which cover $[x,y]$. We arrange these (maybe not all) finitely many intervals the following way:

Choose $U_{t_1}$ such that $x \in U_{t_1}$,

If $y \notin U_{t_1}$ choose $U_{t_2}$ such that $s_1:=\sup U_{t_1}\in U_{t_2}$,

If $y \notin U_{t_2}$ choose $U_{t_3}$ such that $s_2:=\sup U_{t_2}\in U_{t_3}$,


$\vdots$

After a finite number of steps we get $y \in U_{t_{m+1}}$.

Note that $x < s_1 < s_2 \dots < s_m \le y$ and that always ${\rm dil}f|_{U_t}={\rm dil}f|_{\overline{U_t}}$. Now
$$
d(f(x),f(y)) \le d(f(x),f(s_1)) + d(f(s_1),f(s_2)) + \dots +d(f(s_m),f(y)) 
$$
$$
\le {\rm dil}f|_{U_{t_1}}(s_1-x)+{\rm dil}f|_{U_{t_2}}(s_2-s_1) + \dots +  {\rm dil}f|_{U_{t_m}}(y-s_m). 
$$
$$
\le ({\rm dil}_{t_1}f  + \varepsilon)(s_1-x)+({\rm dil}_{t_2}f  + \varepsilon)(s_2-s_1) + \dots +  ({\rm dil}_{t_m}f  + \varepsilon)(y-s_m). 
$$
$$
\le (\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}{\rm dil}_{t}f + \varepsilon) (y-x).
$$
Now $\varepsilon \to 0+$ yields
$$
d(f(x),f(y)) \le (\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}{\rm dil}_{t}f) (y-x).
$$
Since $x,y$ are arbitrary $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}{\rm dil}_{t}f$.
Hope everything is correct. Please check.
